# Grid view validations

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my web application i have grid view control with edit property true. Now i want to use the validation when user not enter anything in text boxes, i not use the edit template i use boundfields. how can i use validation help me thank you.
this is my code

```
                    <Columns>


                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Topic Id">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblsid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("subjectid") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                         <HeaderStyle CssClass="text2" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>                          

                    <asp:BoundField  HeaderStyle-CssClass="text2" HeaderText="SubjectName" DataField="subjectname" /> 
                      </Columns>

   </asp:GridView></td></tr>
```

Comment: Why you don't want to use Edit Template, may we know?

Comment: this was already done by other team. now i get this to modify 
of course i change the source code i placed edit template now but is not possible to give validation when we use boundfields?

Comment: I have edited my answer and put the sample code for validation of a textbox in EditItemTemplate. check this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the BoundField class to create your own and add a validator to it.

In your new class you would override the InitializeDataCell method and get the textbox (Which will exists when in edit mode). Once you have found the textbox, you can add a validator to it.

```
protected override void InitializeDataCell(DataControlFieldCell cell, DataControlRowState rowState)
        {
            base.InitializeDataCell(cell, rowState);

            // First, find the textbox to validate
            TextBox textBox = null;
            foreach (Control ctrl in cell.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl is TextBox)
                {
                    textBox = ctrl as TextBox;
                }
                break;
            }

            // If no textbox is found, this means we are not in edit mode. 
            if (null != textBox)
            {
                InitializeTextBox(cell, textBox);
            }
        }

private void InitializeTextBox(DataControlFieldCell cell, TextBox textBox)
        {
            // Force an Id if none exists.
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.ID))
            {
                textBox.ID = "Text" + DataField;
            }

            // Add RequiredFieldValidator
            var required = new RequiredFieldValidator {ControlToValidate = textBox.ID, Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic, ErrorMessage = ErrorMsgRequired};
            validators.Add(required);
            cell.Controls.Add(required);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply add your validator control inside the gridview Itemtemplate with the control you want to validate.
Try the example below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" runat="server">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CategoryID">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkID" runat="server" CommandName="sel" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.CategoryID") %>'
                                Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.CategoryID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comments">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvComments" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtComments"
                             ValidationGroup="a"   ErrorMessage="enter comments" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CategoryName">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkName" runat="server" CommandName="sel" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.CategoryName") %>'
                                Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.CategoryName") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

<br/>
 <asp:Button ID="btn"  Text="Save" runat="server" ValidationGroup="a" />
```

Textbox **txtComments** is validated with the RequiredFieldValidator **rfvComments**.

Please check.

EDITED: Try to add ValidationGroup="a" in commandfield and same in the requiredfieldvalidator as in below:

```
<asp:CommandField ValidationGroup="a" ButtonType="link" ShowEditButton="true" ShowCancelButton="true" />
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comments">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.CategoryID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvComments" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtComments"
                                            ValidationGroup="a" ErrorMessage="you shouldn't leave the text box empty" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: What do u want to validate? Please clearify if I don't understand.

Comment: see when edit button click then it comes under edit mode with text box when user clear the text box (empty) then click the Update button then error should raise like "you shouldn't leave the text box empty"

Answer (score 2):

capture the GridView [RowCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) event and then validate all the inputs on "Update" CommnadName

```
void YourGridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) {
    if(e.CommandName == "Update") {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow row = ContactsGridView.Rows[index];

        if(!row.Cells[INDEX_OF_COLUMN_TO_VALIDATE].Text.StartsWith("SOME_LETTER")) {
            //your error here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can validate the first character should start with character only how it is possible in rowcommand @ Zarembisty

Comment: ContactsGridview what is that in my page it is not getting there is not intellisense for that ContactsGridview

Comment: replace that with whatever the ID of your GridView is

Comment: ok it is working but, i have some doubt if user not any thing in the text box it should rise the message that textbox shouldn't empty @zarembisty

Comment: i just now added my source code please check out @ zarembisty

Answer (score 0):

first of all get one textbox and than after the that value insert into session and then grid view as a parameter that value give.